# Image of a connected set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let  $f\colon X\longrightarrow Y$ be a function where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces.

If graph of $f$ is connected can we say that image of every connected subset of $X$ is connected too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the circle $S^1$ with coordinates $[0, 1)$, and the function $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = x$. The space $S^1 \times \mathbb{R}$ looks like a cylinder, and the graph of $f$ winds around the cylinder once, finishing above where it started: in particular, the graph is connected. Let $U \subseteq S^1$ be a small open connected neighbourhood of $0$, then $U$ is connected but $f(U)$ is not.

Comment: You can exclude cases like this by requiring path connectedness instead of connectedness and requiring $X$ to be simply connected.

I wonder if this means that any function with a path-connected graph from a simply connected space $X$ to a topological space $Y$ is continuous.

Comment: @Contravariant does this exclude those cases? If I take a (simply-connected) disc and put a tear in it, and pull one side of the tear down and the other up, then this is the (path-connected) graph of some function from the disc to $\mathbb{R}$. But I can take a small connected neighbourhood over where I tore, and this will give me a disconnection.

Comment: You're right, I think I was implicitly assuming $f$ to be continuous, but then it is trivially true.

Comment: @Joppy what if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ ??